# How can I return the first 3 characters after every comma in a string in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a string that I need to seperate into values seperated by commas.  I have achieved this part with the below REPLACE statement:

declare @mc varchar(200)
declare @mc1 varchar(200)
select @mc = 'FRED&#g4;&#4g;MARY&#g4;&#4g;BILL&#g4;&#4g;TIMOTHY&#g4;&#4g;JOHNATHAN'

select @mc1 = REPLACE(@mc, '&#g4;&#4g;',', ')

The replace returns a string 'FRED, MARY, BILL, TIMOTHY, JOHNATHAN'

I then want to have another variable that will return the first 3 characters of each value before the commas, so the above string would be returned as:

'FRE, MAR, TIM, JOH'

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Also happy for this to be done directly to the original @mc variable

Comment: What version `select @@version` of SQL server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 16:50:01   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: )

Comment: But that's my local copy of SQL, the production server could be using an earlier version and I dont have access to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ON SQL Server 2017+ you can make use of *openJson* to split the string into manageble segments and then *string_agg* to assemble the desired result:

```
declare @mc varchar(100)='FRED&#g4;&#4g;MARY&#g4;&#4g;BILL&#g4;&#4g;TIMOTHY&#g4;&#4g;JOHNATHAN'

select String_Agg(v, ', ')
from (select @mc)x(s)
cross apply (
    select Left(j.[value],3) v,  Convert(tinyint,j.[key]) Seq 
    from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(s,';', '","'),'"]')) j
    where Convert(tinyint,j.[key]) % 2 = 0
)j;
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=67e1e064a347e98f0f78f98276a12710)

[image]

Comment: That is awesome, wasn't aware you could do that, was expecting something using a combination of LEFT, CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING with a UNION or some such.  Totally works on my local copy of SQL but I'm working with a devops tool that is quite restrictive.  Fails with syntax errors on the 'from' 'x' and 'j'.  I have not be able to get it to use from and can normally get around it but not sure how to in this example.

Comment: So the tools will already be focused on the table that contains the column with the string in it, so from commands are not normally required.  For example the REPLACE I gave in my example above would b written as REPLACE(<column>, '&#g4;&#4g;',',') can you think of a way to write the above without the unembedded FROM?

Comment: @Corbillion Your question uses a variable `@mc` as sampe data, not a table, hence I used that in my answer above. If you are actually working with data in a table just replace `(select @mc)x(s)` with the table name and use the column name in the `replace(s` <-- part

Comment: thanks I already did that, its failing for the other reason I stated above.  But you solution works in my database after replacing the variables with the table names.  Aslo the production database is 2015 so its failing on the JSON as well :(